# Cypress get URL as a string to use in next commands not working

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to get the url as a string in Cypress. Here is my code:

```
 let schoolDistrictViewLink1 = null;
 cy.url().then(($url) => { schoolDistrictViewLink1 = $url, cy.log($url)})
 cy.log(schoolDistrictViewLink1)
```

When I run the test, the first log properly logs the url, but schoolDistrictViewLink1 is still null.

I cannot get schoolDistrictViewLink1 to equal the url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not work because of the asynchronous nature of Cypress. Cypress themselves advises to use aliases to save values for later use.

> https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases

In you example you can put the value of `cy.url()` in an alias. Which you can get via `cy.get('@aliasName')` later:

Example:

```js
    cy.url().as("schoolDistrictViewLink1");

    // do other things

    // when you need to use the value
    cy.get("@schoolDistrictViewLink1").then((url) => {
      cy.log(url);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to chain commands immediately to `cy.url` then you will not have to do anything just chain.

```js
cy.url()
  .should('eq', 'https://www.website.com/')
```

If you want to use it at a later point in your test you can use a combination of `function()` and `this` keyword

```js
let url
it('check url', function(){
  cy.url().then( u => url = u)
  // later in your test
  cy.get('selector').should('have.text', this.url)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

**Explanation of the problem:**

you are trying to assign the value of the URL to `schoolDistrictViewLink1` in a `callback` function passed to `cy.url()`. This means that the value of `schoolDistrictViewLink1` will not be updated until the callback function is called, which happens **asynchronously** after `cy.url()` is executed.

**Solution:**

you can use the **[async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)** pattern to wait for the value to be updated.

```
async function getUrl() {
  let schoolDistrictViewLink1 = null;
  await cy.url().then(($url) => { schoolDistrictViewLink1 = $url, cy.log($url)});
  return schoolDistrictViewLink1;
}

const url = await getUrl();
cy.log(url);
```

Happy coding !

Comment: This will not work. Cypress commands do not return promises and cannot be awaited. https://medium.com/@NicholasBoll/cypress-io-using-async-and-await-4034e9bab207